# django skip entry when looping over queryset (in template)

Tags: django

I have a `ListView` model, which generates me the required queryset. Then, I my template, I do something like:

```
{% for i in queryset %}

{{i.var1}}

{% endfor %}
```

.. and this works perfectly. But, what I want to do is:

```
{% for i in queryset %}

{% if i.var1 == "mystring" %}

 <skip this entry and do i++>

{% else %}

{{i.var2}}

{% endfor %}
```

.. but how do I `<skip this entry and do i++>`?

Comment: Maybe `if i.var1 == "mystring" i.var2 else <entry>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do this sort of editing then it isn't working perfectly, you should filter these entries out of your queryset inside of your view

```
.exclude(var1="mystring")
```

In the comments you state that the queryset comes from an iterable, so at the very least you'd be able to do list comprehension in the view

```
[i for i in queryset if i.var1 != "mystring"]
```

If this is something you absolutely have to do in a template, then the only way is with the complete surrounding if statement that you already have in your question

Comment: unfortunately, the queryset is coming from an iterable - django has no control over it... So, I need this processing in the template (I know!)

Comment: @JohnJ - It would be interesting to see exactly what that entails because I'd imagine it is something you can manage in a view. But, if it needs to be in a template, then there is no `continue` for the current loop

Comment: @JohnJ - I've added a way in which you would be able to modify the "queryset"/iterable in the view so that its not something you need to do in the template

Answer (score 2):

this may help you

```
{% if i.var1 != "mystring" %}
```

this simply skip mystring and loop counter also increase